# How to detect multiple digits in one image using CNN

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

The network in CNN recognize one digit for one image,
 how can I recognize **two or more digits in one image**.
A proper way I've thought about is modifying the weights in the FC layer. 
In other words, if there is two three digits in a image, the fully connected layer's weight can be expressed as (in tensorflow):

`w_output = __weight_variable([1024, number_of_digits*number_classes], stddev=0.1)`
If we want to recognize one digit in one image, just remove the 
`number_of_digits` in the above statement.

Another question occurred when the number of digits is unknown(Maybe two or more). How to modify the network to recognize all the digits in the image?

Comment: I think it depends on what type of digit recognition you're referring to. If you're imagining some dark-colored digits on a white background, then you could maybe first train an algorithm to detect digits first and then pass the presumably found digits to a image classification network?